# ARM Assembly How to store value from one register into another register

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

Say if register X12 contains the value 5, and I want to move the value in register X12 into X13, how should I accomplish this? I've learned LDR/STR/MOV, but I am confused about which one is the correct way to accomplish this.
Here are the ways I can think of but I think they are wrong:

```
   LDR X13,[X12,#0]
   STR X12,[X13]
   MOV X13,X12
```

Comment: The instruction `mov x13, x12` is correct for this purpose.

Comment: Try to build a mental model of registers vs. memory -- they're both available to the program but only memory has **addresses** & values, whereas the registers just have values.  `LDR` transfers data from memory (at a given address) into a register, `STR` transfers data from a register into memory (at a given address) -- whereas `MOV` transfers data between registers only, so no addressing or memory is involved.

Comment: Transferring data between registers is neither a load nor a store, although it does write a register so it wouldn't be totally weird to say you "load" one register from another.  But it's not a load from memory, so best not to say that.  It's also definitely not a store in computer-architecture terms.

Comment: I think a better model is that registers are an *alternative memory* which is extremely limited in size, but very fast.  Load/store are to transfer from 'memory' to 'register memory'.  The moving in registers is often a sign that your code is not good.  You should use a calculation.  This is the logic behind [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form).  Ie, you code in assembler to be fast, but using register `mov`  is not efficient.  The exception would be context switch code; specific register have specific uses when following some ABI. Otherwise, it is usually bad.

Comment: memory is numbered boxes that you put things in or pull things out of.   registers are post it notes.  when you open one of the boxes to see what is there you write the contents on a post-it note.  or vice versa, what is on a post it note gets written inside the box.  then the box goes back on the shelf.

Comment: terms like read/write, load/store get used in various architectures documentation.  related to memory accesses, which is actually also an incorrect term as it is a bus with an address.  not every load or store, read or write, is to/from an actual memory, sometimes it is peripherals or other logic.   but anyway.  some architectures/instruction sets overload the mnemonic mov or allow for memory to be used in various instructions

Comment: a load store architecture to some extent means you do your work in general purpose registers (add, subtract, etc) and you take separate steps to store/load items to memory as needed.   but some architectures you can add, subtract, shift, etc using memory addresses as an operand and the read/writes are all part of that operation.

Comment: arm is essentially a load store architecture so you do your work in registers, and do memory operations separately.

Comment: arm might have even had a CPY mnemonic, am I remembering right?   but basically mov is used to "copy" the contents of one register to another (the source does not get modified or erased or anything)/

Answer (score 6):

ARM uses the following standard nomenclature for data transfer instructions:

- **Load**: read data from memory and write it to a register.  These instructions have mnemonics starting with `LD`.
- **Store**: read data from a register and write it to memory.  These instructions have mnemonics starting with `ST`.
- **Move**: Read data from one register and write it to another.  These instructions use the `MOV` mnemonic, which is also used for writing an immediate value into a register.

Thus what you want is a move, `MOV X13, X12`.

(Fun fact: the instruction `MOV X13, X12` is really an alias of `ORR X13, XZR, X12`.)